# PHP Fatal error, MongoDB, cursor

Tags: php, mongodb, list, database

I'm trying to set up a simple MongoDB and insert some data. I have to use PHP and I am running the code on external server owned by my uniersity (it is obligatory for me, the server has everything set up). My problem is that I'm using code from tutorialsPoint and everything works great until it reaches '`$list = $db->listCollections();`'. Then I receive the following log:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: not authorized for query on Test.mycol

My issue is that I don't know why this happens and how to solve it. Any suggestions?

code:

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
  # $m = new MongoClient();
   $mongo = new Mongo();
   $db = $mongo->Test;
   $username="4rebacz";
   $password="pass";
   $db->authenticate($username, $password);
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
  # $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $document = array( 
      "title" => "MongoDB", 
      "description" => "database", 
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by", "tutorials point"
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";
   $cursor = $collection->find();

   $str = file_get_contents('dirdata/formdata.txt');
   $json = json_decode($str, true);
   foreach($json as $id => $item)
   {
    $collection->insert($item);
   }

   $list = $db->listCollections();
   foreach($list as $collection)
   {
    echo "$collection \n";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**listCollections** - required administration roles
[Read there](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

> Every database includes the following database administration roles:
>
> dbAdmin Provides the following actions on the database’s
>   system.indexes, system.namespaces, and system.profile collections:
>
> - collStats
> - dbHash
> - dbStats
> - find
> - killCursors
> - listIndexes
> - listCollections
> - dropCollection and createCollection on system.profile only

Comment: OK, may I have one more question? How can I show all records in the DB without using administration roles?

Comment: You should at least know the names of all the collections. And the current user must have rights to this collectionion ...

Comment: otherwise, use the user "admin", or add rights for your user